# Copy tables between two environments - Redshift

Tags: database, copy, migration, amazon-redshift

I have a requirement to copy data  between tables of two different instances in redshift.

The first one is dev environment and the second one is stage environment.

The requirement is to copy a table from dev to stage.

```
Instance 1: Dev
URL      :  link1
username : userdev
password: passdev
schema  : schema1
tablename: table1

Instance 2: Stage
URL:        link2
username:  userstage
password:  passstage
schema:   schema2
tablename: table2
```

Is there a way to copy between these instances?

I do not want to use the copy utility. I need a script.

Comment: unload to s3 then copy from s3 is the route you need to take

Comment: OK. Is it the copy utility? Could you please let me know the steps and code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying a table from one redshift cluster to another redshift cluster(without using s3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047685/copying-a-table-from-one-redshift-cluster-to-another-redshift-clusterwithout-us)

Comment: You could refer following link, its talks about best practice for data move from one environment to other in details, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719339/amazon-redshift-backup-restore-best-practices/51222674#51222674

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at out Unload/Copy Utility: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/master/src/UnloadCopyUtility

The utility automates the process you've described above.

Answer (score 0):

If it one time you can use [copy command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html).

First copy data from instance-1 to S3.
Then from S3 to instance-2.

If you need to do this daily use AWS Lambda with A JDBC connection to redshift with S3 as mediator.